# How do I turn off pub nub logging on iOS in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub

I am using pub nub for push.  There are a ton of helpful logs.  I don't want that sometimes, how can I turn off all logging?

I've gone [here](https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c#logging), and I set all values to 0 rather than 1.  That didn't turn any logging off.

I've set `PNLogger.loggerEnabled(false)` but that doesn't turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

Use the method like this:

[PNLogLevel loggerEnabled:YES];
[PNLogLevel loggerEnabled:NO];

Comment: These code examples were missing from the docs at
https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c#logging 
until a few days ago.